# printing matrix in a separate line

Tags: prolog

I want to print matrix, each row in a separate line, for example

```
?- print_matrix([[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]).
```

And i want to get

```
[a,b,c]
[d,e,f]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to use `write` and `nl` in a recursive rule, like this:

```
print_matrix([]).
print_matrix([H|T]) :- write(H), nl, print_matrix(T).
```

This is the "classic" Prolog solution for list processing, with a fact handling the empty list, and a rule that processes header elements one-by-one.

Answer (score 2):

```
?- maplist(\X^(writeq(X),nl),[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]).
[a,b,c]
[d,e,f]
true.
```

Using [library(lambda)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl). Or:

```
writeqln(X) :-
   writeq(X),
   nl.

?- maplist(writeqln,[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]).
```